# New Virtual Host 301-redirects to old Virtual Host

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I have an apache installed on Debian Linux. A virtual host, which is described in the file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/site.conf, something like that

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
</VirtualHost>
```

I have added new Virtual Host to this file, so now this file looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName site-mirror.com
 ServerAlias *.site-mirror.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
</VirtualHost>
```

and restarted apache

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Now, when I go to site-mirror.com, apache redirects me to site.com (301 redirect)

What could be the problem ?

I will appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Do you have any `.htaccess` on `/var/www/site` ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like 

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

Comment: on your main config file (httpd.conf or apache.conf) how `NameVirtualHost` is defined? is it with `*` or `*.80`. It should be `*:80`

Comment: Seems to be a redirection done at the application level. What is the php CMS used on site.com?

Comment: @regilero, it's WordPress, and there is no NameVirtualHost directive in apache2.conf

Comment: @Malgin: ok so the redirection is done by wordpress as accessing the same website from different domains may lead to bad SEO things. You shoudl check for wordpress specific plugins to support multi-domain access on the same wordpress install, like this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/domain-theme/

Comment: @regilero: thanks, that helped) Has just to change the settings of  WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) in WP. If you like, create the answer, I will accept it

Comment: @Malgin: if you alter the real domain of wordpress to site-mirror.com, then people accessing it from site.com will have a redirect to site-mirror.com

Comment: @regilero: Yes, thanks, I understand that and it suits my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the redirection is done by wordpress to prevent SEO problems. you'll need some wordress specific module to support multi-domain access on the same wordpress installation like [this one, domain-theme](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/domain-theme/).

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Sometimes it seems that it is apache problem, when it has nothing to do with it )

Answer (score 1):

A very quick guess but the fact that both DocumentRoots are the same may be tricking apache and treating it as a redirect, try changing the mirror documentroot and see if you still get the 301.

Dave

Comment: Nope, when I just delete the site.com record, it behaves like there is no host for this DocumentRoot